# Separate IP Range to Separate IPs

Tags: ruby, regex, excel, ip, vba

I have a list of customers in a tab-delimited file, each with a corresponding set of IP ranges. However, I am uploading them to a database that does not accept a range in the third octet. That is, an IP of 24.53.241.150-185 is acceptable, but 24.53.150-185.241 is not.

In order to upload this list to the database, I need to separate IPs with a range in the third octet into separate IPs without ranges in the third octet (eg., 24.53.151.241, 24.53.152.241, etc.), and have this match up in the same format with its corresponding fields of "Customer" and "Admin Email".

How can I do this, using whatever tools would work? I'm flexible (Excel tools, Regex, Ruby, etc.).

**The format of what I currently have:**
[image]

**What this needs to turn into (with the third octet separated into different rows):**

[image]

Comment: Need more specifics. Can you add any columns you want in the DB or are you forced to use the format it already has? Also have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Also are you saying that instead of the single entry like line #2 you could have 75 entries that all have `Harvard | tom@harvard.edu | 34.24.123.*` with a line for each IP from .123 to .198? You need to give a more specific example of how the data has to look in your DB.

Comment: And last but no least, you have `*` for some octets. Does that mean you need an entry for each one 0-255?

Comment: Will AdminEmail always be the same for each Customer?  Please show us what you have tried and where you have run into trouble.  This forum exists to help others with complex formulas or program code, but it is not a free code-writing service.   In VBA, I would create a Class (User Defined Object) and expand the IP addresses into a collection or dictionary.

Comment: Appreciate your help. I clarified the question regarding was needed for the final product. I also determined a solution using Ruby and have listed it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out using Ruby code, and applied it after saving the Excel file as a tab-delimited TXT file.

```
 def expand_lines(line)
  id, inst, ip = line.split("\t")

  ip_compontents = ip.split('.')
  if ip_compontents[2] =~ /(\d+)-(\d+)/
    $1.to_i.upto($2.to_i).map do |i|
      new_ip = [*ip_compontents[0..1], i, ip_compontents[3]].join('.')
      [id, inst, new_ip]
    end
  else
    [[id, inst, ip]]
  end
end

if $0 == __FILE__
  ext  = File.extname(ARGV[0])
  base = File.basename(ARGV[0], ext)
  dir  = File.dirname(ARGV[0])

  outfile = File.join(dir, "#{base}_expanded#{ext}")

  expanded = IO.read(ARGV[0]).split("\n").map {|l| expand_lines(l.chomp)}.flatten(1)
  File.open(outfile, 'w') do |f|
    f.puts expanded.map {|l| l.join("\t")}
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

This is one way to convert your string to a range of ips.

```
def convert_to_range(ip)
  arr = ip.split('.')
  ndx = arr.index { |s| s =~ /-/ }
  f,l = arr[ndx].split('-')
  (f..l).map { |s| [*arr.first(ndx), s, *arr[ndx+1..-1]].join('.') }
end

convert_to_range("24.53.94-105.241")
  #=> ["24.53.94.241", "24.53.95.241", "24.53.96.241", "24.53.97.241",
  #    "24.53.98.241", "24.53.99.241", "24.53.100.241", "24.53.101.241",
  #    "24.53.102.241", "24.53.103.241", "24.53.104.241", "24.53.105.241"]

convert_to_range("24.53-58.105.241")
  #=> ["24.53.105.241", "24.54.105.241", "24.55.105.241", "24.56.105.241",
  #    "24.57.105.241", "24.58.105.241"] 

convert_to_range("24-26.58.105.241")
  #=> ["24.58.105.241", "25.58.105.241", "26.58.105.241"] 

convert_to_range("26.58.105.241-248")
  #=> ["26.58.105.241", "26.58.105.242", "26.58.105.243", "26.58.105.244",
  #    "26.58.105.245", "26.58.105.246", "26.58.105.247", "26.58.105.248"]
```